# How to send event from Activity to service with greenrobot event bus?

Tags: android, android-activity, service, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus-3.0

Simple  EventBus.getDefault().post() bring exception not main thread. How to send event from Activity to service with  greenrobot event bus?

```
chronometer  = (Chronometer)findViewById(R.id.chrono);
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer arg0) {
                long countUp = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - arg0.getBase()) / 1000;
                String asText = (countUp / 60) + ":" + (countUp % 60);
                Log.e("asText", "asText" + asText);
                ChronometerEvents event=new ChronometerEvents();
                event.setTime(asText);
                bus.post(event);
            }
        });



public class ChronometerEvents {
    private String time;


    public ChronometerEvents() {

    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}



public void onEvent(ChronometerEvents freq) {
        Log.e("Chronometer", "Chronometer" + freq.getTime());


    }
```

service class

```
public class NewLocationUpdateService extends Service {

    private EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

      bus.unregister(this);




        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }




    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {




        return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {


        return super.onUnbind(intent);

    }

  public void onEvent(ChronometerEvents freq) {
        Log.e("Chronometer", "Chronometer" + freq.getTime());


    }







}
```

is it posible to send using greenrobot event bus?

Comment: shows us the code. is it intentservice?

Comment: share code you have written in service

Comment: please check my code

Comment: you didn't register for `EventBus` in service

Comment: public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      bus.register(this);

Comment: If it is a intent service then use Intent instead to send event.
It depends on type of service you are using is it Sticky?

Comment: please check added my service class also

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend reconsidering your architecture here. The EventBus is not designed to cross process boundaries and the Android Services don't lend themselves easily to the idea.

The EventBus is a great tool but it is very easy to misuse.

If you want to send information from an Activity to a Service it's best to use Intent's, but if you really need some closer interaction then you should look into binding. The Eventbus should not replace these interactions.

Comment: Eventbus should replace these interactions since their slogan is "Android optimized event bus that simplifies communication between Activities, Fragments, Threads, Services, etc." that means we should be able to communicate between Activities <-> Services. so we can skip binding to a service :/